# Join between two tables based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table `accounts` with columns `ip_from`, `ip_to`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `bytes`.
There is a second table called `all_audit` with columns `project`, `ip`, `time`.
I need to join the tables in order to get a resulting table with columns for `project`, `time` and `bytes`.
Things that need to be considered are that `time` only matches with records which fall between `start_time` and `end_time`. `ip` can match either `ip_from` or `ip_to`.

The schema for the two tables are:

accounts

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ip_from        | char(15)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ip_to          | char(15)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| bytes          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_time     | datetime            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| end_time       | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

all_audit

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| project   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip        | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| time      | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

result

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| project   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time      | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bytes     | bigint(20) unsigned| NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I know it will be a join but I just don’t know where to start. Pointers will be very helpful as I am not that competent yet in sql statements but willing to learn.

Comment: Provide example schema/data, please.

Comment: That sounds like a very bad database design. One table per project? Why? If the entity is "project" then have one projects table with one row per project. This will make it much simpler to query the database. Remember: Additional data should generally only lead to additional rows, not to additional tables.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner. I see what you are saying but if the each project needs to have a sequence of `time` and `bytes`. How is that possible in one table without going into a 3rd dimension?

Comment: @tonythewest has lead the way I think. His answer below has helped me. All I needed was to create a table with three columns. One for `project`, `time` and 'bytes`. I could eventually select records per project. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT aa.project
     , aa.time
     , a.bytes
  FROM all_audit aa
  JOIN accounts a 
    on (aa.ip = a.ip_from OR aa.ip = a.ip_to) 
   AND aa.time BETWEEN a.start_time AND a.end_time
```

Comment: Thank, I'm currently running it and it seems like it's going to take a while. I'll let it run overnight and report back in the morning. Hopefully not an infinite loop or something. If it worked I'll mark it as the correct answer.